# How to stop program for 1 second in Java Android?

Tags: java, android, sleep

I would like the program to work like this:

```
public void onClick(View view){
    method1();
    // sleep for 1 second
    method2();
}
```

I used **Threed.sleep()** but it works like:

```
public void onClick(View view){
    // sleep for 1 second
    method1();
    method2();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View view){
  method1();
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
      method2();
     }
   },1000);
}
```

[Find more about handler here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler)

Comment: a little description would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
   Handler  mHandler1 = new Handler();
     mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        method1();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

and create new Agin handler for other function :

```
   Handler  mHandler2 = new Handler();
     mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        method2();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

2handler give to u 2 s total wait for two fucnction

```
method1()=1s go to sleep
method2()=1s   "" ""
```

if u want have 1 s sleep just use one handler for it not 2 handler 
sry i cant speack english more :)